# Swap Object in GTK (using Python and Glade)

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, glade

I'me trying to make a python app using GTK.
What I want is to have a window with 3 buttons, and I want to switch the widget that is behind when I click one button (see screens for more infos).
Also, if it's possible, I would like to make the buttons toggle buttons, but when I will click on another one, the previous will stay clicked. How to change that ?
Thanks !

Screens :

[image: full page]
[image: project overview]

I tryed loading another .glade file on another var, and use `add1` on the panel to add it, but it didn't work (no error on the terminal).

Comment: 1) you may be interested in [`Notebook`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Notebook.html) 2) if you are not willing to use `Notebook` for some reasons, use [`ToggleButton`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.ToggleButton.html)

Comment: The [widget gallery](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/visual_index.html)  gives a pretty good overview of available widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using Notebook, as Alexander said, is the best way to do it.
Thanks !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).